# How to split a column with multiple attributes into multiple columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file that contains two columns **Activity** & **Result**

**Activity** is a String column that contains three possible values say `a`, `b` and `c`.

The **Result** column contains values from form submissions all grouped together as follows:

```
Result
option1: 2; option2: 4; option3: 2
```

The options are not same for all rows. The options depend on the value in **Activity** column. So, a sample file looks like

```
Activity,Result
a       , "a1: 1; a2: 4; a3: 5"
a       , "a1: 3; a2: 1; a3: 5"
a       , "a1: 4; a2: 3; a3: 5"
b       , "b1: 2; b2: 4; b3: 2"
b       , "b1: 3; b2: 4; b3: 2"
b       , "b1: 1; b2: 3; b3: 1"
```

I want to convert this file into a format that contains the options as columns as follows

```
Activity, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3
a       ,  1,  4,  5,   ,   ,   
a       ,  3,  1,  5,   ,   ,    
b       ,   ,   ,   ,  2,  4,  3
```

Is there a way to do this in Excel? Also, I don't mind creating separate files for each of the options (a, b and c).

Answer (score 0):

Place your data as shown in sheet 1, create sheet 2 and leave it blank, the following code will give the output you have outlined...

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Activity"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 2).Value = "a1"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 3).Value = "a2"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 4).Value = "a3"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 5).Value = "b1"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 6).Value = "b2"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 7).Value = "b3"

Dim c() As String
c = Split("a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3", ",")

Dim firstActivity, lastActivity, t1, t2 As Integer
firstActivity = 2
lastActivity = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim Result As String

For i = 2 To lastActivity
    Result = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
    For i2 = 0 To 5
        t1 = InStr(1, Result, c(i2), 1)
        If (t1 = 0) Then GoTo skip
        t1 = InStr(t1, Result, " ", 1)
        t2 = InStr(t1, Result, ";", 1)
           If (t2 = 0) Then
             t2 = InStr(t1, Result, """", 1)
           End If
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, i2 + 2).Value = Mid(Result, t1, t2 - t1)
skip:
    Next i2
    Next i
```

**Input** (sheet 1)

```
Activity    ,Result
a   , "a1: 1; a2: 4; a3: 5"
a   , "a1: 3; a2: 1; a3: 5"
a   , "a1: 4; a2: 3; a3: 5"
b   , "b1: 2; b2: 4; b3: 2"
b   , "b1: 3; b2: 4; b3: 2"
b   , "b1: 1; b2: 3; b3: 1"
```

**Output** (Sheet 2)

```
Activity    a1  a2  a3  b1  b2  b3
a   1   4   5           
a   3   1   5           
a   4   3   5           
b               2   4   2
b               3   4   2
b               1   3   1
```

Don't mind the columns they are lined up perfectly but the site formatting messed it up when I paste it here. You can even accomplish this with formulas instead of VBA as well but the macro I wrote above accomplishes exactly what you outlined, if there is details you forgot to mention and want me to modify the code please tell me. Of course the best solution is if possible to stop having data inputted this way.